# Messaging system flow into database

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, message, database-schema

**Simple or Personal type messaging :**

*I tried to follow the other answers here but can't understand how they are really saved into the database*
[image]

**Sender:**
 Sends message and saved/tag under **"Sent"** message

**Receiver:**
Receives message and tag as **"Inbox"** message

**My problem:** *When I tried to send a message and update my field "Placeholder" to "Sent", the receiver coudn't see it in his "Inbox" because it was already set to "Sent".*

*btw **Placeholder** is like a message status(Inbox, Sent, Trash), I created 3 custom views displayed in Tab form for my joined tables (Inbox, Sent and Trash)*

**Question:**

1. Do I have to insert 2 records everytime a message was sent? (Sent and Inbox)
2. Is that the best database schema to follow if I only need a Simple/personal message?

Comment: Will they only be sent from and sent to users in your database?

Comment: And could each message only be sent to a single user?

Comment: @user1032531 yes...indeed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do I have to insert 2 records everytime a message was sent? (Sent and Inbox)

No, just one time.

2. Is that the best database schema to follow if I only need a Simple/personal message?

I would recommend keeping it very simple.  Note that "Sent_two" should obviously be "sent_to".  This will do everything you need with the possible exception of the place holder part which I currently don't understand your intent.

[image]

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 11/30/14 09:07:59
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Users` (
  `idUsers` INT NOT NULL,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idUsers`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`messages`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`messages` (
  `idmessages` INT NOT NULL,
  `Subject` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Body` TEXT NULL,
  `Date` DATETIME NULL,
  `sent_from` INT NOT NULL,
  `sent_two` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idmessages`),
  INDEX `fk_messages_Users_idx` (`sent_from` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_messages_Users1_idx` (`sent_two` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_messages_Users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sent_from`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Users` (`idUsers`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_messages_Users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sent_two`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Users` (`idUsers`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Well, I love the simplicity of the database but it doesn't answer how "Inbox", "Sent" and "Trash" being handled.

Obviously there only 1 message to send (think of an email message). 


So how will I create a display that shows the sent message under "Sent"? then the Receiver receives the message in his "Inbox"?


That is 1 of the reason why I add a placeholder(just like a message status) for "Inbox", "Sent" and "Trash".. but I understand what you said..its getting complicated..

Comment: @Raf  As for as trash, just add two tinyint column to messages: one for sender_trash and one for receiver_trash.  To find messages sent from user 123, just query the messages table where sent_from is 123 and it is not sender trash.  Similarly could do the same for users inbox, senders trash, and inbox trash.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I got your point now.. So I don't need any field like "placeholder" to categorize a message? Its just matter of a query and showing them under "Sent" or "Inbox" by just using labels? am I right?

Comment: @Raf  Assuming all users are internal and there is only receiver per message, you are good.

Comment: @Raf  If this answer answers your question, please select it as your answer.

Comment: @user1032531 What if the message would be coming from tywo types of people, employee and customers?